# Как ввести матрицу?

Tags: java

Есть задание

> Разработать программу, осуществляющую ввод вещественной матрицы произвольного размера, все элементы которой различны. Найти скалярное произведение строки, в которой находится наибольший элемент матрицы, на столбец с наименьшим элементом.

Вот программа, набирала её в эклипсе

```
public static void main (String[]args) throws NumberFormatException,IOException
{
       BufferedReader matr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       System.out.println("Введите размереность матрицы");
       System.out.println("Количество строк матрицы");
       int a;
       a = Integer.parseInt(matr.readLine())+1;
       System.out.println();
       System.out.println("Количество столбцов матрицы");
       int b;
       b = Integer.parseInt(matr.readLine())+1;
       System.out.print("Введите поэлементно матрицу");
       int i,j;
       int[][]mas=new int[a][b];
       for (i=1;i<a;i++){
           for (j=1;j<b;j++){
               mas[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(matr.readLine());
           }
       }
       int min,max,k_min,k_max;
       min=mas[1][1];
       max=mas[1][1];
       k_min=1;
       k_max=1;
       for(i=1;i<a;i++){
           for (j=1;j<b;j++){
               if(mas[i][j]>=max){max=mas[i][j];k_max=i;}
               if(mas[i][j]<=min){min=mas[i][j];k_min=j;}
           }
       }
       int pr=1;
       for (i=1;i<a;i++){
           pr=mas[i][k_min]*pr;
       }
       for(j=1;j<b;j++){
           pr=mas[k_max][j]*pr;
       }
       System.out.println("Результат");
       System.out.println("Исходная матрица");
       for (i=1;i<a;i++){
           for (j=1;j<b;j++){
               System.out.print(Integer.toString(mas[i][j])+"\t");
           }
           System.out.println();
       }
       System.out.println("Скалярное произведение строк равно "+Integer.toString(pr)+"");
}
```

вот только вещественные числа, понятное дело не считает. подскажите где и на что нужно поменять `integer`. Пыталась вставлять `double` и `float`, ошибки выдает((

Comment: тебе самому то оформление кода нравится?

Comment: эклипс второй раз в жизни вижу, уж как смогла ><

Comment: Пардон, коммент относился к форматированию текста в топике. Что касается кода, то написание не зависит же от того, на чем пишешь) Красота не зависит ни от эклипса, ни от нетбин..

Comment: Зачем люди используют BufferedReader, если Scanner в 100 раз проще и удобней?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `mas, min, max` декларируйте как `double`
2. Парсите вещественное число как `Double.parseDouble()`
3. Да и пробежка индексов в Java начинается с нуля
4. При нахождении минимума обычно начальное значение минимума принято ставить как `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`, а для максимума соответственно как `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` - тогда это гарантирует корректное нахождение минимакса.
5. Я бы не стал выкидывать `Exception`ы сразу из `main`, лучше возьмите все в `try-catch` блок с интеллигибельным `printStackTrace()`

Comment: ругается что i и j целого типа, а все остальное вещественного

Comment: @noel о господи, ну не делайте из меня компилятор то! Скорее всего `k_min` и `k_max` объявлены у вас `double`, а должны быть `int`. Смысл сводится к тому, что `double` должно быть все что относится к элементам матрицы, а все что относится к индексам матрицы целое.

Comment: всё, я сделала, спасибо

Comment: @noel если ответ принят, то в этом форуме принято нажимать на галочку с левой стороны от принятого ответа, в противном случае в следующий раз вам могут и не помочь :)

Comment: вообще я через float сделала в итоге, но не важно)

Answer (score 0):

Для вещественных используй Double.parseDouble вместо Integer.parseInt()  + замени все int-ы на double.   
Теперь что касается скалярного произведения: зачем спрашивать количество строк и отдельно количество столбцов матрицы, если она должна быть квадратная?